# Pod1 can't communicate with Pod2 when using istio-demo-auth.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have 2 pods with 1 spring boot app in each one of them.

Each pod has a istio-proxy in it.

When I use istio+without mtls (by applying istio-demo.yaml in istio-1.0.3-release/install/kubernetes/), app in P1 can communicate fine with app in P2. There is a service corresponding to each spring boot app. The app in P1 is communicating using a URL like

```
http://service2Name:port/path
```

However, when I switch to istio with mtls (by applying istio-demo-auth.yaml in istio-1.0.3-release/install/kubernetes/), the same app in P1 can't communicate with the app in P2.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://service2Name:port/path": Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

Any suggestions on where to start debugging? I am an istio newbie.

Comment: Can you check the logs of the istio-proxy? You can do it by running command `kubectl logs <your_pod_name> istio-proxy`